# Problem in schwarz inequality

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces

To prove the schwarz [inequality they proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proofs),they showed that the vector z is orthogonal to the vector v. If they are orthogonal, then why didn't they have written in this way : $\displaystyle \|u\|^{2}=|v\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}$?

Instead of this: 
$${\displaystyle \|u\|^{2}=\left|{\frac {\langle u,v\rangle }{\langle v,v\rangle }}\right|^{2}\|v\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}}$$

Another thing is that, how they got the below? I mean, I don't see the another  $\|v\|^{2}$ in the below line.   $$\left|{\frac {\langle u,v\rangle }{\langle v,v\rangle }}\right|^{2}\|v\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}={\frac {|\langle u,v\rangle |^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}}+\|z\|^{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since $v$ and $z$ are orthogonal, then $\frac {\langle u,v\rangle }{\langle v,v\rangle }v$ and $z$ are too. So, by Pythagorean theorem, $${\displaystyle \|u\|^{2}=\left|{\frac {\langle u,v\rangle }{\langle v,v\rangle }}\right|^{2}\|v\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}}$$ 
The second part follows of $\|v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$.